# Filtering column in R

Tags: r, excel

I'm still a beginner to R and trying to filter the AF column in this dataset to include values <=0.01 and the blank spaces.

Have used the dplyr filter command to filter one of the other columns and that has been fine so I know it works just don't know how to apply it to the current command I want to run. Any help would be really appreciated!

Below is what I'm running.

```
maf <- filter(maf.tb, maf.tb$"t_depth" >=20)
maf.2 <- filter(maf,maf$"AF" <=0.01 & "")
```

[image: sample of dataset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue with the OPs code is that we need the OR operator `|` here, not AND (`&`).

For the following code to work we must be sure AF is a numeric variable. Otherwise we may need to transform it into numeric with
`as.numeric()` beforehand

```
maf %>%
    filter(AF<=0.01 | is.na(AF))
```

additional comments:
never use the dollar sign subset (`x$y`) for dynamic selection of columns, it is much safer to use the double brackets (`x[["y"]]`).
And, in Dplyr, we may use other methods more consistent with its general approach, just call the variable name (as in `filter(x, y == z)`)